# Azure Storage Response Code for 429

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

We have our service which is behind a GatewayServer. The Gateway server applies a retry itself if the downstream dependencies return an appropriate response code and depending on the time out set on the Gateway server it may retry.

Going through the Azure Storage docs it appears that the storage client doesn’t return a 429 response as evident from this page :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-error-codes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-performance-checklist

From Retries Section of the above link  :
In some cases, the storage service may throttle your application or may simply be unable to serve the request due to some transient condition and return a "503 Server busy" message or "500 Timeout". The client libraries are aware of which errors are retry-able and which are not.

Since the Storage Client library doesn’t return 429, we can’t make a decision on whether a retry should be attempted or not ? The important thing is how to determine if a given 5xx error is retryable on our end, so that we don’t retry and return a 429 to the gateway server which retries all such requests ? The idea is that we want to avoid retries on different layers and let the Gateway Server make a decision based on the response from the downstream services and the timeout set.

Is there a header or a particular error message which we can pivot on to make this decision ?

Answer (score 0):

Great question! They key thing to understand here is that Storage Service itself will never retry failed operations. For each operation the service will simply return a HTTP status code. Onus lies on the client to infer these status codes and perform retries if needed.

If we take the example of .Net storage client library, there's a built-in retry mechanism which intercepts error codes and perform retries. If I am not mistaken, the default retry mechanism is `Exponential Retry`.

However you can write your own retry logic and inject it in your code. Whenever an error occurs then, your retry logic would come in place and the requests will be retried.

I wrote a blog post on this very topic some time ago that you may find useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/12/30/storage-client-library-2-0-implementing-retry-policies/. I do realize that it is a pretty old post and a lot has changed but that should give you some idea about how to implement your own retry policies.

In this blog post I wrote some sample code which will do a retry when you delete a container and immediately create a new container by the same name. Since deleting a container can take some time so under normal circumstances you will get a 409 error code back from the service which is not retryable by default. But with this custom retry policy, your code will retry creating blob container for "x" number of times before giving up.

```
public class ContainerBeingDeletedRetryPolicy : IRetryPolicy
{
    int maxRetryAttemps = 10;

    TimeSpan defaultRetryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    public ContainerBeingDeletedRetryPolicy(TimeSpan deltaBackoff, int retryAttempts)
    {
        maxRetryAttemps = retryAttempts;
        defaultRetryInterval = deltaBackoff;
    }

    public IRetryPolicy CreateInstance()
    {
        return new ContainerBeingDeletedRetryPolicy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), 5);
    }

    public bool ShouldRetry(int currentRetryCount, int statusCode, Exception lastException, out TimeSpan retryInterval, OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        retryInterval = defaultRetryInterval;
        if (currentRetryCount >= maxRetryAttemps)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //Since we're only interested in 409 status code, let's not retry any other operation.
        if ((HttpStatusCode)statusCode != HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //We're only interested in storage exceptions so if there's any other exception, let's not retry it.
        if (lastException.GetType() != typeof(StorageException))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var storageException = (StorageException)lastException;
            string errorCode = storageException.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode;
            if (errorCode.Equals("ContainerBeingDeleted"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here's the code that uses this retry policy:

```
static string accountName = "<storage account name>";
static string accountKey = "<storage account key>";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
    string blobContainerName = "temp-" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    IRetryPolicy linearRetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), 10);
    blobClient.RetryPolicy = linearRetryPolicy;
    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
    blobContainer.Create();
    Console.WriteLine("Blob container created.");
    blobContainer.Delete();
    Console.WriteLine("Blob container deleted.");
    IRetryPolicy containerBeingDeletedRetryPolicy = new ContainerBeingDeletedRetryPolicy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), 10);
    BlobRequestOptions requestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions()
    {
        RetryPolicy = containerBeingDeletedRetryPolicy,
    };
    blobContainer.Create(requestOptions);
    Console.WriteLine("Blob container created.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```